# Weierstrass Representation and height function

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let be $(g,\omega)$ the Weierstrass data of a immersion $X: \Sigma\to \mathbb{R}^3$, i.e., $g$ a meromorphic function and $\omega$ a holomorphic 1-form such that
$$X=\mathcal{Re}\int_\gamma (\frac{1}{2}(1-g^2)\omega,\frac{i}{2}(1+g^2)\omega,g\omega).$$
 Suppose that, away from of critical point of height function $x_3$ there is a local complex coordinate $w$ such that $x_3=\mathcal{Re}(w)$, that is,
$$\mathcal{Re}(\int_\gamma g\omega)=\mathcal{Re}(w).$$

Under what conditions I have that
$$g\omega= dw?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally around a point $p$, write $\omega = m (z) dz$ and $dw = w'(z) dz$.  Then your equation $g \omega = dw$ is equivalent to 
\begin{equation} g(z) m(z) = w'(z).\end{equation}
Since $p$ is not a critical point, we have that $w'(z) \neq 0$.  Hence, you require either that (1) $g$ and $\omega$ are nonzero at $p$ or (2) the order of the pole of $g$ at $p$ is equal to the order of the zero of $\omega$ at $p$.

Note that since $X$ is an immersion, if $\omega$ has a zero of order $2m$ at $p$, then $g$ must have a pole of order at most $m$ at $p$.  In particular, (2) is never satisfied.

So you must have that $g$ and $\omega$ be nonzero at $p$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, for all local complex coordinate $w$ such that $x_3=\mathcal{Re}(w)$, I have $g\omega = dw$? Is it that?

Comment: That is correct.  Sometimes a slightly different version of the Weierstrass representation (as hinted to in my answer): $X = \mathcal{Re} \int_{\gamma} \left( \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{g} - g\right) dh, \frac{i}{2} \left(\frac{1}{g} + g\right) dh, dh\right)$.  This has the feature that $(g,dh)$ refer to the geometry of the surface quite nicely.  If $dh$ has a zero, then the height function is not a local complex coordinate (that is, the surface has a horizontal tangent plane).  Also, $g$ corresponds to the Gauss map of the surface (after using the inverse stereographic projection).